# PHP, using two counters to decide top results of an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a block of PHP code where I'm using two counters (one specifically for a particular key of `featured` if the value is 1.

So far, the counter works by putting any records where `featured == 1` in `$cnt1` and everything else in `$cnt2`. However, this doesn't do anything for my sorting.

How can I make this so that the final array puts all featured (`$cnt1`) records at the top of the array/the first results?

```
if(count($myresults)>0){
    foreach ($myresults as $key => $value) {
        $id = $value->ID;
        if(get_post_meta($id,'_awpcp_extra_field[36]',true) !='' && get_post_meta($id,'_awpcp_extra_field[37]',true) != ''){
            $lat = get_post_meta($id,'_awpcp_extra_field[36]',true);
            $lon = get_post_meta($id,'_awpcp_extra_field[37]',true);
            $area  = get_post_meta($id,'_awpcp_extra_field[38]',true);
            $amnt = get_post_meta($id,'_awpcp_price',true)/100;
            $ttle = get_the_title($id);
            $link = get_permalink($id);
            $desc = get_the_excerpt($id);
            $date = get_the_time('m/d/Y',$id);
            $is_featured = get_post_meta($id,'_awpcp_is_featured',true);
            $imgpath = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($id,'dailymag-featured');

            $counter_name = ($is_featured == 1) ? 'cnt1' : 'cnt2';
                        
            $ress[$$counter_name]['featured']  = $is_featured;
            $ress[$$counter_name]['lat']  = $lat;
            $ress[$$counter_name]['lon']  = $lon;
            $ress[$$counter_name]['area']  = $area;
            $ress[$$counter_name]['amnt'] = $amnt;
            $ress[$$counter_name]['ttle'] = $ttle;
            $ress[$$counter_name]['link'] = $link;
            $ress[$$counter_name]['desc'] = $desc;
            $ress[$$counter_name]['date'] = $date;
            $ress[$$counter_name]['count'] = $counter_name;
                        
            if($imgpath){
                $ress[$$counter_name]['imgs'] = $imgpath;
            }else{
                $ress[$$counter_name]['imgs'] = '/wp-content/uploads/2022/03/fairfax-4670d9c9.jpeg';
            }
            $$counter_name++;
       }
    }
```

Comment: If you want to keep creating the array this particular way, you can really only sort if afterwards, I suppose. If you did not assign to `$ress[$$counter_name][...]` directly, but gathered your data in a new array first, then you could perhaps alternate between array_push and array_unshift ... still, cumbersome. Probably made much more sense, if you assigned your data like this, `$ress[$counter_name][] = ['featured' => ..., 'lat' => ...]` (notice the second $ removed from $counter_name) - then `$ress['cnt1']` and `$ress['cnt2']` could be simply concatenated together afterwards.

Comment: But where is your data coming from in the first place? If that is a result of a `WP_Query` or `get_posts` or something similar - then you should be able to sort it in the query already, https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#order-orderby-parameters

Comment: the code is not optimal to read whats going on there. It seems, that you overwriting your last result with the next one so the array `$ress` will only contain the last element of `$myresult`. 2nd you did not initiate your variables. $cnt1 and $cnt2 should be set to `0` before you start to count and you should avoid the double dollar $$var_name.

one approach: put everything you need in a simple array (counter, lat, lon, etc) and put this array in two different result arrays (featured, non-featured). after that, you can work with your results.